# What should I know and watch from The Walking Dead series before watching The Walking Dead: Daryl Dixon?

Tags: suggested-order, the-walking-dead, the-walking-dead-daryl-dixon

I recently learned that there is a new spin-off TV series in *The Walking Dead* universe that focuses on Daryl Dixon, and is set in France: ***The Walking Dead: Daryl Dixon***.

What do I need to watch or know from the other *The Walking Dead* shows before I start this one? Are there any important plot points from the other shows that are relevant to this spin-off? Which episodes, seasons, or shows are essential or relevant for understanding and appreciating this spin-off?

Here is what I already know and don’t know about *The Walking Dead* universe:

- I have watched the original *The Walking Dead* TV series but stopped following it sometime after the Saviors/Negan arc, before the Whisperers arc began (middle of Season 9).

> I stopped watching it after Rick left.

- I have read *The Walking Dead* comic books until the final issue, and I believe the original TV series ended similarly to the comics (but please correct me if I’m wrong, and if there are any significant differences relevant to *The Walking Dead: Daryl Dixon*).
- I have watched *Fear the Walking Dead*, but stopped watching in the middle of Season 3.
- I have not watched *The Walking Dead: World Beyond* or *The Walking Dead: Dead City*.

I don’t mind spoilers. You can reveal any plot details without hiding text in spoiler markup.

##### What should I know and watch from *The Walking Dead* series before watching *The Walking Dead: Daryl Dixon*?